# Pass XML Data as input to stored procedure

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My XML Data / record passed to SQL stored procedure and SP ran successfully records loaded. but some time i getting following error message

**Error**

```
Warning: mssql_execute() [function.mssql-execute]: stored procedure execution failed in
```

MS SQL Store procedure

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddEmployee] (@XmlString ntext)
AS
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
DECLARE @XmlInput XML;
SET @XmlInput = CAST(@XMLHeader AS XML)
INSERT INTO Employee
(
    ID,
    EmpName,
    Sal
)
Select
T.N.value('ID[1]', 'varchar(250)') as CompanyName,
T.N.value('EmpName[1]', 'varchar(250)') as WebsiteUrl,
T.N.value('Sal[1]', 'varchar(250)') as PrimaryServices
from @XmlInput.nodes('/Record/Emp') as T(N)
```

**PHP Snippet**

```
$procName = "AddEmployee";
$xml_data = "<record><Emp><ID>6</ID><EmpName>ganesh</EmpName><Sal>6500</Sal></Emp><Emp><ID>7</ID><EmpName>jayachandran</EmpName><Sal>7500</Sal></Emp><Emp><ID>8</ID><EmpName>kotis</EmpName><Sal>8500</Sal></Emp></Record>"
$params[0][0] = "XmlString";
$params[0][1] = $xml_data;
$params[0][2] = SQLVARCHAR;

$proc = mssql_init(proc_name,$connid);
for($i=0;$i<count($params);$i++){
    $rtn = mssql_bind($proc,'@'.$params[$i][0],$params[$i][1],$params[$i][2]);      
}
$rtn_status = mssql_execute($proc);
```

Comment: You are missing the root `<Record>`, which should precede `<Emp>`

Comment: Thanks for pointing, but i have added that <record>in the stored procedure itself.

Comment: Could you solved the problem? I have to do the same thing, I like to know how to do

Comment: s, problem for, i will share this very soon